# How to solve "<frame not available>" in pycharm concurrency diagram

Tags: python, multithreading, debugging, pycharm, deadlock

I am trying to debug a deadlock condition using Pycharm Profesinoal 2019.3.1 and the Concurrency Diagram. I can see the deadlock and the different threads, but when I click in one of them I get the messages "frame not available" instead of the stack of each thread:

[image]

How can I make the stackframe of each thread visible?

Comment: I'm also seeing this behavior.